# how to calculate the electric power required to rotate an object from 500 gram

Tags: power, motor

I want pull an object (like a rabbit) over grass for teaching my dessert buzzard to catch the object. I made a machine to pull the object about a 50 meters. I can control machine with a remote controller. The machine works perfectly on a flat surface like a road with concrete.

Now I want to use the machine in the field (grass.) But the object doesn't move because the motor is too weak.

I want a speed of 8m/s.  What motor do I need?

Specifications of the object:

- leather
- rough surface
- oval
- 30 10 10 -> lxwxh
- 500 gram

Specifications of the surface:

- grass
- dry
- grass length = +- 5 cm

Specifications of the current motor:

- 30 watt
- 12 V DC
- 3000 rpm

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Do you know the coefficients of static and sliding friction between your object and the grass? That is pretty critical information.

Comment: You also need to specify the acceleration and speed. 30 W would be plenty with the right gear ratio.

Comment: How fast do you want it to move? Higher speed requires more power. Is the object smooth or spiky on the bottom? Does it slide or roll? Is the grass perfectly level? Is is perfectly flat?

Comment: @DaveTweed, thank you for the reaction. I want a speed of 2 m/s. The object is made of leather with a rough surface and is 30 cm long and 10 cm high and 10 cm width. The object is oval. The problem is not that the object goes to slow but in the grass it doesn't move. The object moves perfect on flat surfaces but only in the grass it sticks. Have you enough information?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I don't know the coëfficiënt between leather and grass. I'm looking for it on the internet but i didn't find it.

Comment: Get a spring scale (or a fish scale) and measure the friction. You are going to have a lot of variables, length of grass, wet, dry, etc etc, but some information is better then none, so you can get an upper bounds.

Comment: @DaveTweed I have update my question. Do you have enough information?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a problem of mechanical rather than electrical engineering, and probably not answerable even in that context given the unclear conditions such as applicable friction over an irregular ground / vegetation surface

Answer (score 4):

Moving itself on grass and dragging something on grass are two different things. For moving itself you can use bigger wheels to deal with the rougher surface, but need gear down for to compensate for the increased torque requirement to maintain the same speed. But dragging something...you need a new motor. No way around that.

Coefficient for rolling friction of 0.3 is already very high and is for something like for soft wheels on a dirt road where it is light enough it won't sink in. For small wheels in tall grass it will be much higher. Larger wheels reduce the effect of roughness a bit. 5cm grass would need like...>20cm wheels

0.3 means rolling on wheels takes 30% of the pushing/pulling force of just lifting it up. Ideally you want it to be zero. At >1 it is easier to just pick the thing up rather than roll.

I laid everything out so you should only need to read it from top to bottom and look backwards for variables, never forward. I also tried to lay it out so hopefully you know where everything is coming from (as long as you have a basic understanding of power, torque, force, and friction...maybe even if you don't).

\$ m_{robot} = \$ mass of robot (kg)

\$ m_{bait} = \$ mass of bait (kg)

\$ g = \$ acceleration of gravity \$ =9.81m/s^2\$

\$ W_{robot} = \$ weight of robot (N) \$ =m_{robot}\times g\$

\$ W_{bait} = \$ weight of bait (N) \$ =m_{bait}\times g\$

\$v=\$ speed (m/s)

\$\mu_{roll}\$ = coefficient of rolling friction for wheels

\$\mu_{drag}\$ = coefficient of friction for dragged bait

\$\theta=\$ angle of incline

\$ \eta = \$ drive efficiency (between 0 and 1 for 0% to 100%). Use 1 if you need output power (or in calculations of required output like torque). Use actual efficiency if you need input power

---

\$ F_{roll} =\$ force of rolling friction for robot only \$=W_{\perp robot} \times \mu_{roll}=W_{robot}cos(\theta)\times \mu_{roll}\$

\$ F_{drag} =\$ force of friction dragging bait only \$=W_{\perp drag}\times \mu_{drag}=W_{bait}cos(\theta)\times \mu_{drag}\$

\$ a = \$ desired acceleration \$(m/s^2)\$

\$F_{robot.accelerate} = \$ EXTRA force required to accelerate robot \$ =m_{robot} \times [a +gsin(\theta)]\$

\$F_{bait.accelerate} = \$ EXTRA force required to accelerate bait \$ =m_{bait} \times [a +gsin(\theta)]\$

---

\$ r_{wheel} \$ = radius of driven wheel (m)

\$ \tau_{roll} \$ = torque required to maintain speed of just the robot \$ = F_{roll} \times r_{wheel}\$

\$ \tau_{drag} \$ = torque required to maintain speed of just the bait \$ = F_{drag} \times r_{wheel}\$

\$ \tau_{friction} = \$ torque required to overcome friction losses and keep everything moving at constant speed = \$\tau_{roll} +\tau_{drag}\$

\$ \tau_{robot.accelerate} = \$ EXTRA torque required to accelerate just the robot \$ = F_{robot.accelerate} \times r_{wheel}\$

\$ \tau_{bait.accelerate} = \$ EXTRA torque required to accelerate just the bait \$ = F_{bait.accelerate} \times r_{wheel}\$

\$ \tau_{accelerate}= \$ total EXTRA torque required to accelerate everything\$=\tau_{robot.accelerate}+\tau_{bait.accelerate}\$

\$ \tau_{total}= \$ total torque required to accelerate everything\$=\tau_{friction}+\tau_{accelerate}\$

---

\$ P_{robot.continuous} = \$ Continuous power to maintain speed of robot \$= F_{roll} \times v \times \frac{1}{\eta}\$

\$ P_{bait.continuous} = \$ Continuous power to maintain speed of bait \$= F_{drag}\times v \times \frac{1}{\eta}\$

\$ P_{robot.peak} = \$ Peak power to accelerate just robot \$= [F_{roll} + F_{robot.accelerate}] \times v \times \frac{1}{\eta}\$

\$ P_{bait.peak} = \$ Peak power to accelerate just bait \$= [F_{drag} + F_{bait.accelerate}] \times v \times \frac{1}{\eta}\$

\$ P_{total.continuous} = \$ Total continuous motor power required \$= P_{robot.continuous} + P_{bait.continuous}\$

\$ P_{total.peak} = \$ Total peak motor power required \$= P_{robot.peak} + P_{bait.peak}\$

---

Speed-dependent losses such as aerodynamic resistance or speed-dependent drive-train losses have been neglected.

You can measure the dragging force and rolling force with a pull scale and use the equations above to calculate the coefficient of friction. Accelerate slowly and smoothly when you pull or else the friction force measured will include acceleration forces. Then you can use that in other equations to figure out the power at various speeds and required torque.

All that should get you pretty close as long as you can make good friction force measurements to get good coefficients of friction. Worst case, you can assume a coefficient of 1 for rolling and dragging friction which is normally totally overkill, but with small wheels in tall grass it becomes much more reasonable. The extra power and torque would just go into acceleration.

Answer (score 2):

Use a spring scale to measure the drag force of the rabbit on "beton" (concrete?). Do the same thing for the grass.

The ratio of these two numbers is the same as the power ratio you'll need for the motor, all other things (speed, slope, flatness, etc.) being equal.

Comment: Beton is indeed concrete.